# Need an algorithm to resize an organization chart to fit window

Tags: javascript, css, algorithm, performance, pdf-generation

### Context:

I need to be able to render any organization hierarchy tree onto a web page of any given dimension and then, using a headless browser, convert the page to a PDF, while keeping the text legible so that large companies can print it on large print outs or zoom in to see it.

End goal:

- Company can create a hierarchy of their organization through an app
- Visually preview it through the web interface
- Save to a PDF (and optionally print a physical copy)

This allows them to have a single source of truth and to visually represent their organization's tree.  Some organizations would like to define a large pdf size (eg, 24" x 36") and be able to take their PDF on a flash drive to Kinkos and print it and display it in their office.

Note: There is no upper limit on the depth or width of an organization.  Currently have companies that are 300+ across and 5 levels deep.  So that is why I need an approach that will scale.

### Current Approach:

Currently, I'm taking a brute force approach by scaling the font-size of the parent container.

- Set font-size on chart element to 0
- Create a while loop and increment the font-size by some increment (ex. 0.1px)
- Let the browser redraw the chart
- Check if it's overflowing
- if not overflowing, increment & repeat, else, decrement by increment amount and exit loop

Large charts need finer increments, otherwise they don't render at all.

Example, say the font-size increment is 0.5.  If a chart is so large 0.5px is overflowing, the current script will increment - see it's overflowing - then revert to 0, meaning it's not displayed.

If I lower the increment, then most smaller charts render time will increase drastically.

### Data structure:

```
Seat: {
   name: 'Seat Name',
   children: Array<Seat>,
}
```

### Prototype:

https://github.com/danfoust/org-chart-prototype

### Desired Solution

I could feed a recursive data structure & window dimensions to a function and it could efficiently determine the best font-size to fit the generated DOM in the window.

If this is possible with CSS, that would also be great.  I'm using Puppeteer & by extension Chromium, so if there's some latest and greatest CSS magic, that would be awesome.

Comment: What is the point in wanting it to fit it in the viewport? If the company is big you won't be able to fit in an iPhone 5S viewport AND keep it readable. Working on a good pdf)html format with well thought referencing/links will likely be a better solution.

Comment: The use case is not mobile devices.  These are enterprise clients.  They want to be able to save the output to a file and print it off on a large print out or share the file with employees and view on desktop.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. When you have 10000 people in a company, you can't print it on a single page. Or maybe your case is only applicable on small/medium size company? If a file is enough then as I mentioned before think about a structure of links/references that will enable your html/pdf file to redirect users on appropriate sub categories or upper categories

Comment: You can improve the running time of your current solution with an [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search). Start with a font size of 1. If the chart fits, keep doubling the font size until it doesn't fit. Then you have a lower and upper bound on the font size, and you can do a binary search to find the largest font size that fits. (If font size 1 doesn't fit, then the lower bound is 0 and the upper bound is 1, and you do a binary search within that range.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed @user3386109's recommendation and found the upper bound then did a binary search.  For 300 seats, this cut the time to find in half.

```
'use strict';

const $ = (selector) => document.querySelector(selector);
const $$ = (selector) => document.querySelectorAll(selector);

// Prevent loop from blocking render for 3 ms
async function isOutOfBounds(chart, w, h) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(chart.scrollWidth > w || chart.scrollHeight > h), 3);
  });
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const scrollbarPX = 16; // Prevent empty last page

const screenWidth = window.innerWidth - 1;
const screenHeight = window.innerHeight - scrollbarPX;

const headHeight = $('.header').scrollHeight;
const footHeight = $('.footer').scrollHeight;

const maxChartHeight = screenHeight - headHeight - footHeight;

(async () => {
  // Set each page to window dimensions
  const pages = $$('.page');
  for (const page of pages) {
    page.style.width = `${screenWidth}px`;
    page.style.height = `${screenHeight}px`;
  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  
  const cache = {};

  const charts = $$('.chart');
  for (const chart of charts) {
      let cacheKey = `${chart.scrollWidth}x${chart.scrollHeight}`;
      if (cache[cacheKey]) {
          chart.style.fontSize = `${cache[cacheKey]}px`;

          // Handle rare case where same sized charts render differently at same font-size
          if (!await isOutOfBounds(chart, screenWidth, maxChartHeight)) {
             continue;
          }
      }

      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      let max = 1;

      while (1) { // Get upper bound
          chart.style.fontSize = `${max}px`;

          if (await isOutOfBounds(chart, screenWidth, maxChartHeight)) break;

          max *= 2;
      }

      let mid;

      while (1) { // Use binary search
          mid = max / 2;

          chart.style.fontSize = `${mid}px`;

          if (!(await isOutOfBounds(chart, screenWidth, maxChartHeight))) break;
      
          max = mid;
      }

      // The binary search takes the first number that works
      // which may not be the best number.  Let's try scaling 
      // up by a fraction of the working number.
      let incr = mid / 10;
      let size = mid + incr;
      while (1) {
         chart.style.fontSize = `${size}px`;

          if (await isOutOfBounds(chart, screenWidth, maxChartHeight)) {
              chart.style.fontSize = `${size - incr}px`;
              cache[cacheKey] = size - incr;
              break;
          }

          size += incr;
      }
    }

    // Using waitForSelector with Puppeteer
    $('body').classList.add('complete');
})();
```